# Vicidial GoAutodial - move MySQL database to another server

Tags: asterisk

I have installed GoAutodial version 3.3 (this is essentially an automated installer for the Vicidial autodialer which uses Asterisk to place calls).
It automatically installs a MySQL database on the same host.

I would like to move the database to another server (just the MySQL database, not the Vicidial applications). It uses two MySQL databases - asterisk and goautodial. Both just need to move over to my database server.

There is no documentation on Vicidial or GoAutodial websites to do this. Google brings up nothing. I have no idea where to find the configuration files which point to the location of the database. Possibly this isn't even contained in config files but hardcoded in one of the scripts (?).

Can anyone point me where the config files would be or how to go about that?

Comment: to what extent is GoAutodial open source?  for my edification.

Comment: GoAutoDial is 100% open source, no commercial support either.